# All records got updated when I only update 1 record MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

So when I click the `Confirm` button, it's only supposed to update 1 row but all rows got updated with the same values. Idk what I did wrong as this code works for my other table. No errors given by VB.net.

```
Dim provider As String
Dim connString As String
Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

Private Sub btnConfirm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click
        Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are the data correct?",
                                                         "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                                         MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If result = DialogResult.Yes Then

            provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\user\Desktop\PU\SEMESTER 4\Visual Programming\Hospital Databases\Patient DB.accdb"
            connString = provider
            myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim str As String = "UPDATE [Nurse] SET [NurseName] = @NurseName, [Dept] = @Dept, [Gender] = @Gender, [Shift] = @Shift WHERE [ID] = @ID"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NurseName", txtName.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept", txtDept.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", txtGender.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Shift", txtShift.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Could it be that some other code set all the values of `[ID]` in the table to the same value before your update code?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, no there's no code like that

Comment: Well... The code you've shared only updates where that ID column matches. Please provide a [mre], your problem isn't reproducible with the current code.

Comment: Just to check, are all the values of `[ID]` in the table different before that update statement?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, yes and it's still different because I'm not updating the ID, only the other 4, which all now have the same values

Comment: @ConfusedCoder Are you *sure* that the values in the database are wrong, and that it is not just the code that is reading and displaying the data that is in error? (You didn't mention how you're viewing the data, so I have to ask.)

Comment: I don't think it has anything at all to do with the problem, but just so you know: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes, because when I open the Access itself, the values are wrong (all duplicated)

Comment: Also probably nothing to do with the problem, but you should make a `New OleDbConnection` for each query and call `.Dispose()` on it after use, rather than re-use the same connection.

Comment: It could be possible that this section some how translates to `True` : `WHERE [ID] = @ID` like `1=1`. Rename the `ID` parameter and try again. And make sure you don't have `WHERE [@ID] = @ID`

Comment: Is ID the primary key of the table in the database?

Comment: @Mary, yes it is